# Event Error: In reference to Event Constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a calender work properly by inputting events in the code. I'm still inexperienced with ASP.NET so I'm not sure how to figure this problem out. The error that I keep getting is: "Event" does not contain a constructor that takes 7 arguments.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DateTime d1;

    anEvent[0] = new Event("Event1", "Event one", "08/01/2014", "20.00", "Connie", "222-222-2222", "connie@gmail.com");

    anEvent[1] = new Event("Event2", "Event two", "08/15/2014", "80.00", "Cathryn", "555-555-5555", "cathryn@gmail.com");

    anEvent[2] = new Event("Event3", "Event three", "09/05/2014", "50.00", "Charles", "888-888-8888", "charles@gmail.com");

    foreach (Event myEvent in anEvent)
    {

        String anEventDate;

        anEventDate = myEvent.EventDate;

        d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(anEventDate);

        Calendar2.SelectedDates.Add(d1);

    }
}







 using System;

 using System.Collections.Generic;

 using System.Linq;

 using System.Web;

 using System.Web.UI;

 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

 using System.Configuration;

 using System.Data.SqlClient;

 using System.Data;





 public partial class CurrentEvents : System.Web.UI.Page
 {

Event[] anEvent = new Event[3];

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DateTime d1;

    anEvent[0] = new Event("Event1", "Event one", "08/01/2014", "20.00", "Connie", "222-222-2222", "connie@gmail.com");

    anEvent[1] = new Event("Event2", "Event two", "08/15/2014", "80.00", "Cathryn", "555-555-5555", "cathryn@gmail.com");

    anEvent[2] = new Event("Event3", "Event three", "09/05/2014", "50.00", "Charles", "888-888-8888", "charles@gmail.com");



    foreach (Event myEvent in anEvent)
    {

        String anEventDate;



        anEventDate = myEvent.EventDate;

        d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(anEventDate);

        Calendar2.SelectedDates.Add(d1);

    }



}



protected void Calendar2_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{

    String todayDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); ;

    String calendarDate;

    for (int i = 0; i < Calendar2.SelectedDates.Count; i++)
    {



        calendarDate = Calendar2.SelectedDates[i].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

        if (e.Day.Date.CompareTo(Calendar2.SelectedDates[i]) == 0)
        {

            if (calendarDate.CompareTo(todayDate) < 0)
            {

                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;



            }

            else

                if (calendarDate.CompareTo(todayDate) > 0)
                {

                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;



                }

                else

                    if (calendarDate.CompareTo(todayDate) == 0)
                    {

                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

                    }

                    else
                    {

                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;

                    }

        }

    }

}



protected void Calendar2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    String selectedDate;

    int foundDate = 0;



    selectedDate = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");



    foreach (Event myEvent in anEvent)
    {

        if (selectedDate.Equals(myEvent.EventDate))
        {

            this.ControlNewEventControl.updateControl(sender, e, myEvent.EventName, myEvent.EventDescription, myEvent.EventDate, myEvent.EventFee, myEvent.ECordNm, myEvent.ECordNum, myEvent.ECordEml);

            ErrorLabel.Text = "";

            foundDate = 1;

        }



    }

    if (foundDate == 0)
    {

        this.ControlNewEventControl.updateControl(sender, e, "", "", "", "", "", "", "");

        ErrorLabel.Text = "* There is no Event Scheduled for that Date.<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Please Choose Another Date.";

    }



    Page_Load(sender, e);

}



   /* SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database2.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

    DateTime Date;



    try
    {

        dbConnection.Open();

        string SQLselectQuery = "SELECT EventDate FROM Event";

        using (SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(SQLselectQuery, dbConnection))
        {

            SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                Date = reader.GetDateTime(0);

                Calendar2.SelectedDates.Add(Date);

            }

        }

    }

    catch (SqlException exception)
    {

        Response.Write("<p>Error code " + exception.Number + ": " + exception.Message + "</p>");

    }

    finally
    {

        dbConnection.Close();

    }

}



protected void Calendar2_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{

    String todayDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); ;

    String calendarDate;

    for (int i = 0; i < Calendar2.SelectedDates.Count; i++)
    {



        calendarDate = Calendar2.SelectedDates[i].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

        if (e.Day.Date.CompareTo(Calendar2.SelectedDates[i]) == 0)
        {

            if (calendarDate.CompareTo(todayDate) < 0)
            {

                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

            }

            else if (calendarDate.CompareTo(todayDate) > 0)
            {

                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

            }

            else if (calendarDate.CompareTo(todayDate) == 0)
            {

                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

            }

            else
            {

                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Fuchsia;

            }

        }

    }

}



protected void Calendar2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database2.mdf;Integrated Security=True");



    try
    {

        int count = 0;

        dbConnection.Open();

        string SQLselectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Event WHERE EventDate = @EventDate";

        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(SQLselectQuery, dbConnection);

        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventDate", Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString());

        using (selectCommand)
        {

            SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                count++;

                Ename.Text = reader.GetString(1).ToString();

                Escript.Text = reader.GetString(2).ToString();

                EDate.Text = reader.GetDateTime(3).ToString();

                EvFee.Text = reader.GetDecimal(4).ToString();

                ECordNm.Text = reader.GetString(5).ToString();

                ECordNum.Text = reader.GetString(6).ToString();

                ECordEml.Text = reader.GetString(7).ToString();

            }

        }

        if (count == 0)
        {

            Ename.Text = "";

            Escript.Text = "There is no Event for this Date";

            EDate.Text = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString();

            EvFee.Text = "";

            ECordNm.Text = "";

            ECordNum.Text = "";

            ECordEml.Text = "";

        }

    }

    catch (SqlException exception)
    {

        Response.Write("<p>Error code " + exception.Number + ": " + exception.Message + "</p>");

    }

    finally
    {

        dbConnection.Close();

        Page_Load(sender, e);

    }

} */

protected void Ename_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
}
```

Comment: The error is clear - the `Event` class does not have a constructor that takes 7 arguments.  Post the code for `Event` (if it's your own class) and we can tell you more.

Comment: I'm not really sure which code to post. Do I post the main aspx page?

Comment: @NikkiStars - No, the code for the `Event` class.  This error has nothing to do with the markup.

Comment: I'm not sure if I put the right one up. I'm still new to this.

Comment: @NikkiStars - Somewhere in your project you should have code that starts with `public class Event {` - the code for *that* class is what we're asking for.

Comment: Alright, I added the code.

Comment: @NikkiStars Not the class `CurrentEvents` the class `Event`, Is that a class you wrote or where is it from. Please remove the code for `CurrentEvents` we don't need that.

Comment: Its from my project for one of my classes. I don't have one named Public class Event.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the code you posted is incomplete - somewhere there must be a definition for the class `Event`, otherwise you wouldn't get the error you're seeing.

The error message itself is clear - the class `Event` does not have a constructor that takes 7 arguments.  Inferring from the code you posted, I would expect there to be a class somewhere in your project (or another referenced project), and it might look something like this:

```
public class Event
{

    public string EventID { get; set; }

    public string EventName { get; set; }

    public string EventDate { get; set; }

    public string EventFee { get; set; }

    public string EventCoordinator { get; set; }

    public string EventCoordinatorSSN { get; set; }

    public string EventCoordinatorEmail { get; set; }
}
```

This is only a guess - it could be set up with private fields (i.e., `private string eventDate`, etc) rather than properties, for example.  The important item here is that you have a class with fields/properties but it only has a default (parameterless) constructor.

So when you try to do the following: `new Event("Event1", "Event one", "08/01/2014", "20.00", "Connie", "222-222-2222", "connie@gmail.com")`, the compiler looks for a constructor in the `Event` class that accepts 7 string arguments, but it can't find one (hence the error).

There are a few ways to resolve this, depending on how the class is actually designed.  You could add a constructor that takes 7 string arguments and assigns them to the 7 fields, like this:

```
public Event(string ID, string name, string date, string fee, string coordinator, string ssn, string email)
{

    eventID = ID;
    eventName = name;
    eventDate = date;
    eventFee = fee;
    eventCoordinator = coordinator;
    eventCoordinatorSSN = ssn;
    eventCoordinatorEmail = email;
}
```

This will assign the 7 arguments to the 7 respective fields.

Another option is to use automatic properties and object initialization.  This would allow you to initialize the fields via the automatic properties (see the code I posted initially in this answer), and would look like this:

```
anEvent[0] = new Event() {
                 EventID = "Event1",
                 EventName = "Event one",
                 EventDate = "08/01/2014",
                 EventFee = "20.00",
                 EventCoordinator = "Connie",
                 EventCoordinatorSSN = "222-22-2222",
                 EventCoordintaorEmail = "connie@gmail.com"
};
```

This will create a new instance of the `Event` class and assign the provided values to the fields via the properties.

There's a few other issues here (such as using `string` for everything rather than `DateTime` for date, `decimal` for currency, etc), but since this is a class project the instructor may not have gotten to that yet, so we can just stick with `string`.

Without seeing the code for the `Event` class we can't give you more detailed help, but hopefully this answer will give you some ideas on what is going on and where to look.